# Writing custom utility classes in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

In a project I have I have many elements that need padding at different breakpoints so I thought I'd do something similar to what Bootstrap already does.

```
@include media-breakpoint-up(xl) {
 .px-xl-25{
     padding: 0 25%;
 }
}

@include media-breakpoint-up(lg) {
    .px-lg-25{
        padding: 0 25%;
    }
}

@include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
    .px-md-25{
        padding: 0 25%;
    }
}

@include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
    .px-sm-25{
        padding: 0 25%;
    }
}
```

Hopefully you can see what I'm going for but this feels extremely ineffective.

I know that in Scss you can loop so is there a way to loop through each breakpoint and say I want this class at each breakpoint, with different values?

Here is how Bootstrap do it in v4:

```
// stylelint-disable declaration-no-important

// Margin and Padding

@each $breakpoint in map-keys($grid-breakpoints) {
  @include media-breakpoint-up($breakpoint) {
    $infix: breakpoint-infix($breakpoint, $grid-breakpoints);

    @each $prop, $abbrev in (margin: m, padding: p) {
      @each $size, $length in $spacers {
        .#{$abbrev}#{$infix}-#{$size} { #{$prop}: $length !important; }
        .#{$abbrev}t#{$infix}-#{$size},
        .#{$abbrev}y#{$infix}-#{$size} {
          #{$prop}-top: $length !important;
        }
        .#{$abbrev}r#{$infix}-#{$size},
        .#{$abbrev}x#{$infix}-#{$size} {
          #{$prop}-right: $length !important;
        }
        .#{$abbrev}b#{$infix}-#{$size},
        .#{$abbrev}y#{$infix}-#{$size} {
          #{$prop}-bottom: $length !important;
        }
        .#{$abbrev}l#{$infix}-#{$size},
        .#{$abbrev}x#{$infix}-#{$size} {
          #{$prop}-left: $length !important;
        }
      }
    }

    // Negative margins (e.g., where `.mb-n1` is negative version of `.mb-1`)
    @each $size, $length in $spacers {
      @if $size != 0 {
        .m#{$infix}-n#{$size} { margin: -$length !important; }
        .mt#{$infix}-n#{$size},
        .my#{$infix}-n#{$size} {
          margin-top: -$length !important;
        }
        .mr#{$infix}-n#{$size},
        .mx#{$infix}-n#{$size} {
          margin-right: -$length !important;
        }
        .mb#{$infix}-n#{$size},
        .my#{$infix}-n#{$size} {
          margin-bottom: -$length !important;
        }
        .ml#{$infix}-n#{$size},
        .mx#{$infix}-n#{$size} {
          margin-left: -$length !important;
        }
      }
    }

    // Some special margin utils
    .m#{$infix}-auto { margin: auto !important; }
    .mt#{$infix}-auto,
    .my#{$infix}-auto {
      margin-top: auto !important;
    }
    .mr#{$infix}-auto,
    .mx#{$infix}-auto {
      margin-right: auto !important;
    }
    .mb#{$infix}-auto,
    .my#{$infix}-auto {
      margin-bottom: auto !important;
    }
    .ml#{$infix}-auto,
    .mx#{$infix}-auto {
      margin-left: auto !important;
    }
  }
}
```

This obviously looks cleaner but I'm unsure as to how the spacing values are defined?

An attempt

```
$percentages: 5, 10, 15, 20, 25;

// sm, md, lg, xl
@each $breakpoint in map-keys($grid-breakpoints) {
    @include media-breakpoint-up($breakpoint) {
        @each($percentage in $percentages)
        .px-#{$breakpoint}-#{$percentage}{
            padding: 0 #{$percentage}%;
        }
    }
}
```

However, it does not like the percentage symbol.

Attempt 2

```
$percentages: (
    5: 5%, 
    10: 10%, 
    15: 15%, 
    20: 20%, 
    25: 25%
);

// sm, md, lg, xl
@each $breakpoint in map-keys($grid-breakpoints) {
    @include media-breakpoint-up($breakpoint) {
        @each $name, $percentage in $percentages{
            .px-#{$breakpoint}-pct-#{$name}{
                padding: 0 $percentage !important;
            }
        }
    }
}
```